# Can I Set Condition For A Replacment In "Text File Changes" in Installshield 2011?

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2011

I'm using "Text File Changes" feature in IS2011. I have a file and I want to replace 2 strings:

1. replace the string always
2. replace the string only if a checkbox was checked by user in install dialog

How can I set a condition for a replacement in Installshield 2011?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I realized that you can't put a condition in a replacement which I don't understand why Flexera did not implemented it in Installshield.
However for a workaround I replace the string with itself case the preoperty that replaces it has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

In IS2010, I've done conditionalized "Text File Changes" operations by creating a separate, empty component that I associate the TextFileChange item with.

You can then place a condition on the component.